# Aligning legend constructs using Row

Tags: legending, grid-layouts, row

Im trying to make a legend with data labelled in groups. I'm doing this by combining `SwatchLegends` using `Row`, `Column` and `Grid`. Here is an example of a `Row` constructed legend:

```
   Framed[
 Row[
  {
   SwatchLegend[
    {Red, Green, Blue},
    {"label1", "label2", "label3"},
    LegendLabel -> "group1",
    LegendFunction -> "Frame"
    ],

   SwatchLegend[
    {Yellow, Purple},
    {"label4", "label5"},
    LegendLabel -> "group2", 
    LegendFunction -> "Frame"
    ],

   SwatchLegend[{Orange},
    {"label6"},
    LegendLabel -> "group3", 
    LegendFunction -> "Frame"
    ]
   },
  Alignment -> Top]
 ]
```

[image]

As you can see the option `Alignment -> Top` does not cause the legend objects to align at the top as I would expect. Interestingly, if I use `Grid` it works pretty much how I expect (with some extra spacing between the `Grid` elements):

```
Framed[
 Grid[
  {{SwatchLegend[{Red, Green, Blue},
     {"label1", "label2", "label3"},
     LegendLabel -> "group1",
     LegendFunction -> "Frame"],
    SwatchLegend[{Yellow, Purple},
     {"label4", "label5"},
     LegendLabel -> "group2", 
     LegendFunction -> "Frame"],
    SwatchLegend[{Orange},
     {"label6"},
     LegendLabel -> "group3",
      LegendFunction -> "Frame"]}},
  Alignment -> Top]]
```

[image]

Is this a bug? Am I using a wrong setting when using `Row`?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `Multicolumn` and it works as expected.

```
Framed[Multicolumn[{SwatchLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"label1", 
     "label2", "label3"}, LegendLabel -> "group1", 
    LegendFunction -> "Frame"], 
   SwatchLegend[{Yellow, Purple}, {"label4", "label5"}, 
    LegendLabel -> "group2", LegendFunction -> "Frame"], 
   SwatchLegend[{Orange}, {"label6"}, LegendLabel -> "group3", 
    LegendFunction -> "Frame"]}, 3, Alignment -> Top]]
```

[image]

or ddd vertical and horizontal space with `Spacings -> {0, 0}`

```
Framed[Multicolumn[{SwatchLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"label1", 
     "label2", "label3"}, LegendLabel -> "group1", 
    LegendFunction -> "Frame"], 
   SwatchLegend[{Yellow, Purple}, {"label4", "label5"}, 
    LegendLabel -> "group2", LegendFunction -> "Frame"], 
   SwatchLegend[{Orange}, {"label6"}, LegendLabel -> "group3", 
    LegendFunction -> "Frame"]}, 3, Alignment -> Top, 
  Spacings -> {0, 0}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** An alternative approach is to replace `"Frame"` with a custom `LegendFunction`:

```
ClearAll[legendFunc]
legendFunc[pos_: (Top -> Top)] := Framed[#, FrameStyle -> Gray, 
    RoundingRadius -> 5, FrameMargins -> 0, BaselinePosition -> pos] &

Framed[Row[{SwatchLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"label1", "label2", "label3"},
     LegendLabel -> "group1", LegendFunction -> legendFunc[]], 
   SwatchLegend[{Yellow, Purple}, {"label4", "label5"}, 
    LegendLabel -> "group2", LegendFunction -> legendFunc[]], 
   SwatchLegend[{Orange}, {"label6"}, LegendLabel -> "group3", 
    LegendFunction -> legendFunc[]]}, Spacer[1]]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

`Grid` and `Multicolumn` are my preferred solutions. However, if you *have to* use `Row` you can wrap each element with `Pane` and use the option `BaselinePosition -> Top -> Top`:

```
ClearAll[baselinePos]
baselinePos[pos_: (Top -> Top)] := Pane[#, "BaselinePosition" -> pos] &;

Framed[Row[baselinePos[] /@ 
   {SwatchLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"label1", "label2", "label3"}, LegendLabel -> "group1",
      LegendFunction -> "Frame"], 
    SwatchLegend[{Yellow, Purple}, {"label4", "label5"}, LegendLabel -> "group2",
      LegendFunction -> "Frame"], 
    SwatchLegend[{Orange}, {"label6"}, LegendLabel -> "group3", 
      LegendFunction -> "Frame"]}]]
```

[image]

Use `Spacer[1]` as the second argument in `Row` to get

[image]

Use `baselinePos[Bottom -> Bottom]` to get

[image]